# EXIF - wrong returned metadata when invoked for the second time and any further invocation

Tags: javascript, exif-js

I'm using the following code along with the EXIF.js library to extract metadata from images:

```
Extract_Image_File_Metadata = function (p_Element) {
    :
    :
    var l_Thumb = document.getElementById(p_Element) ;

    EXIF.getData(l_Thumb, function() {
        var allMetaData = EXIF.getAllTags(l_Thumb);

        console.log("For File: " + document.getElementById(p_Element).src + " - EXIF result: " + JSON.stringify(allMetaData.DateTime)) ;
        
    :
    :
}
```

where the relevant HTML code is:

```
<img id="Shown_Image" 
     style="width:100%;height:99%;object-fit: scale-down; overflow: hidden ;display:block" 
     src="" alt=""
>
```

When I run the program and invoke FOR THE FIRST TIME the Extract_Image_File_Metadata function, the retrieved data is correct. Then, I change the image shown in the same
 element (by replacing the value of the "src" attribute) and invoke again the funtion Extract_Image_File_Metadata; the information returned is wrong as showm in
the console (pasted below; note that the filename is formed by the full date and time).

```
For File: http://10.0.0.3:53457/20230911_094059.jpg - EXIF result: "2023:09:11 09:40:59"
For File: http://10.0.0.3:53457/20230911_094225.jpg - EXIF result: "2023:09:11 09:40:59"
```

If I restart the program and invoke the function for the first time where the image in focus is `20230911_094225.jpg` (the second image in the previous scenario), I do get the correct result:

```
For File: http://10.0.0.3:53457/20230911_094225.jpg - EXIF result: "2023:09:11 09:42:25"
```

What am I doing wrong?

### Edit

I had some progress from additional tests. It turned out that, after the first invocation to `EXIF.getData`, any additional invocation will return `undefined` (instead of `true` or `false`) even when the second (and third and...) invocation was triggered **without** changing the image of the element.

This is more information though things appear to be more obscure.

Answer (score 0):

After lots of trial-error cycles, I found one post that made me think of an alternative to resolve this weird behavior and, after intensive tests of this approach, it very much appears to be a reliable solution. Here it is:

Whenever the image source needs to be replaced by a new one, the `<img>` element needs to be dropped and re-created into the DOM since, apparently, the "old" instance of the element keeps the information of the previous image (this is just a pure, wild and unverified guess of mine).

One this drop-re-create mechanism was set in place, everything works like a charm.